# How to create progress bar with JQuery into JSF page

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I want to create progress bar prototype in JSF page. This code is used to create simple html progress bar:

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // Progressbar
                $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                    value: 50
                });                         
            });


           </script>

                <!-- Progressbar -->
            <h2 class="demoHeaders">Progressbar</h2>    
            <div id="progressbar"></div>
```

This code visualizes simple progress bar. A backing bean will make `for` cycle and will return to the progress bar the percentage of the completed task. My big mystery is how I can pass the value of the completed task from the Java method back to the JS code? And how I can make AJAX call automatically every time when the `for` value is increased?

Comment: This is easier with PrimeFaces `<p:progressBar>` which supports server side interaction by ajax: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf With "plain vanilla" jQuery you've got to write a lot of boilerplate Java/JavaScript code to integrate jQuery seamlessly into JSF or to look for nasty "hidden button" hacks.

Comment: One more specific question: I can create `for` cycle that can simulate some progress and I can send the value using getter/setter to the JS code. and I can put the progress bar into `<div>` of `form` that can be executed via AJAX. The interesting part is how the AJAX part will take the value from the getter/setter in order to make the progress bar "alive". Maybe if there is a way to make a call from the bean back to the JSF page?

Comment: You could use the "hidden button" hack which updates a `<h:outputScript>` which prints a global JS variable representing the current progress and then invoke it with JS `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I'm curious how prime faces developers develop their progress bar? Maybe the same way?

Comment: No, absolutely not. They have developed their own JS ajax engine and JSF view handler which seamlessly integrates jQuery in JSF lifecycle, resulting in easier interaction between the two by PrimeFaces UI components. It's open source, take a look if you're interested. I wouldn't recommend reinventing/homegrowing it if you're already asking questions which indicate a lack of conceptual understanding how the basic stuff works "under the covers".

Comment: One more specific question: I will need JSF component library which will have long support cycle and quick bug fix. Which of these would you recommend: RichFaces, PrimeFaces or IceFaces? Looking at the examples I like PrimeFaces

Comment: @user1285928 Just for info: if you prefer you can do the same thing with RichFaces: [RichFaces Progress Bar](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=progressBar&sample=ajaxProgressBar&skin=blueSky). Using one framework or another depends on many factors...